# How to apply filtering over order by and distict in django orm?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

```
Name            email                 date
_________________________________________________

Dane            dane_1@yahoo.com        2017-06-20
Dane            dane_2@yahoo.com        2017-06-20
Dane            dane_3@yahoo.com        2017-06-20
Dane            dane_4@yahoo.com        2017-06-20
Kim             kim@gmail.com           2017-06-10
Hong            hong_1@gmail.com        2016-06-25
Hong            hong_2@gmail.com        2016-06-25
Hong            hong_3@gmail.com        2016-06-25
Dane            dddd@gmail.com          2017-06-04
Susan           Susan@gmail.com         2017-05-21
Dane            kkkk@gmail.com          2017-02-01
Susan           sss@gmail.com           2017-05-20
```

I can get the first entries of each unique by using `EmailModel.objects.all().order_by('date').distinct('Name')`. this returns

```
 Name            email                 date
_________________________________________________

Dane            dane_1@yahoo.com        2017-06-20
Kim             kim@gmail.com           2017-06-10
Hong            hong_1@gmail.com        2016-06-25
Susan           Susan@gmail.com         2017-05-21
```

What i want to do here is to only include it in the result if the very first entry is something different like more filtering over it? for ex- i don't want to include it in the result if the first email id is dane@yahoo.com for Dave and only include it if it is something different.

Expected result:
if the email for Dane is not dane_1@yahoo.com then

```
 Name            email                 date
_________________________________________________


Kim             kim@gmail.com           2017-06-10
Hong            hong_1@gmail.com        2016-06-25
Susan           Susan@gmail.com         2017-05-21
```

Comment: It will not work as it will fetch the next instance of that same key. What you have done is just filtered one email id. My question is filtering over the very first instance value. Fetch out all the first instance and if the first instance of each entry doesn't satisfy another filtering exclude it from the first result.

Comment: Hello @comrade49 *if the email for Dane is not dane_1@yahoo.com then* - is it only for **Dane** or you want this for all records which have name in their email ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`F()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions) expressions with [`__istartswith`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#istartswith) lookup to exclude those emails which starts with their name so:

```py
EmailModel.objects.exclude(email__istartswith=F('Name')).order_by("date").distinct("Name")
```

Or you'd like to avoid the `Name` in entire email so you can use [`__icontains`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#icontains) lookup so:

```py
EmailModel.objects.exclude(email__icontains=F('Name')).order_by("date").distinct("Name")
```

Comment: Any filtering over this, results in picking of the very next instance which matches this filtering. Whereas what I want to achieve is be done on the first result we get from the first query.  Should I go with the plain approach. For ex- store the first unique value result in one variable and then select only those values making another query to the model. and then do my further filtering?

Comment: @comrade49 The queryset will exclude all the entries which names starts with their email, also it will give you only one instance of particular name, according to `date` field.

Comment: @comrade49 Can you please clarify what kind of queryset do you exactly want?

Comment: Hello @comrade49 Can you provide expected results within your question?

Comment: @AnkitTiwari please see the expected result i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Well, You can try something crazy like this:

```
   variable = modelname.objects.filter(
        ....=....).values(
        'mention_the_column_names_if_you_need_any'
    ).order_by(
        'mention_the_column_name_to_be_sorted'
    ).distinct()
```

Reply to this message if the issue still persist.

Comment: that's what if you do this, your objects which are not matching the filtering will get filtered out for example dave_1@yahoo.com but it will match with dave_2@yahoo.com and that way you will still have dave entry in your final resultant queryset. What I did was use the first query which gave me the first entries of each unique value in my table based on a unique value identifier. I stored their ids in a separate variable and then did one more query to filter out those ids and with the required statuses. It worked this way.

Answer (score -2):

Supposed your model name is User
So for order by with filter you can used

```html
User.object.filter(parameters).order_by(parameters)
```

Comment: please read the question as to what the original problem is and also please double-check your answer before posting. For ex- your answer has a typo, it should be objects and not object.